# Photoshop technique (Strong fog/mist effect around an object)

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, effect

[image]

Hello, stack exchange community. I was browsing Facebook timeline and found this photo, maybe someone can suggest how does this photo was captured or maybe some PS technique might be applied to achieve such kind of result.

Comment: Please see [[PSA on “What's this effect?” questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions) and edit your question and title accordingly -- thanks!

Comment: Is it OK to copy an image from FB and post it here with no attribution ? I would say no.

Comment: I think there should be no problem for that, I am not using that for any of my personal purposes, just looking for suggestion how such technique was achieved.

Comment: Even if it may not be a legal requirement, I doubt you will appreciate if someone use one of your picture with no attribution. It doesn't cost you much :)